# converting string to float/number for numerical operations in javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having some issues converting a string to a number for numerical calculations in javascript/knockout

I have the following to calculate the total cost of an order in a knockout form

```
self.totalCost = ko.computed(function() {
   var total = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < self.itemNumbers().length; i++)
       //somehow convert the price to a number here so then I can add it 
       total += self.itemNumbers()[i].item.price;
   return total;
});
```

The display shows nothing, however, when I change "return total" to "return i" the total then displays. I'm assuming means the prices are strings and can't be added. When I output the prices in a table they show up as a decimal (such as 19.99) but I'm not sure if they're actually numbers or strings.

**edit below**

I used parseFloat to convert the values. Now, in the table that outputs the result I used typeof() and it shows number. The result still isn't summing properly.

Is there anything else I can do to check the values as to why they're not summing? Can I check each individual value that's being added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe..  total += Number(self.itemNumbers()[i].item.price);

Comment: Nope, doesn't display. Does what I said about returning i make sense? Would this mean that the price isn't a number?

Comment: You should be able to breakpoint in javascript console and check it out. Hard to say without knowing more about itemNumbers.

Comment: I updated my post above. Is there anyway to display the type for price? Would that show whether they're strings or numbers?

Comment: Checkout [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: I used parseFloat and converted it to a number. Now it's not adding, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a jsfiddle for it?